# Xcode build failed, cannot convert value of type NSError

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying a basic message extension tutorial in xcode, and while my code is verbatim from the tutorial, the build keeps failing with the following error:

Cannot convert value of type '(NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type '((Error?) -> Void)?'

Obviously, I'd like this fixed, but as someone very new to Swift, I'd also appreciate an explanation as to why.

```
 @IBAction func sendMessageButtonPressed() {
        self.activeConversation?.insertText("lorem ips!", completionHandler: { (error:
            NSError?) in

        })
    }
```

Comment: try just `error in`

Comment: The NSError -> Error transition should be explained in the Xcode 8 release notes.

Comment: @LeoDabus like this? completionHandler: { (error:
            error in)

Comment: `completionHandler: { error in // your code  }` You don't need to specify the type. It is inferred. Just choose any name for your error variable

Answer (score 0):

`NSError` has turned into just `Error`.